# Ubuntu Ambiance top windows not appearing gray

Tags: gnome

I recently installed ubuntu tweak and a pack of icons called fs-icons-ubuntu. Soo far it worked well. But! When i costumize my theme, i can't get the normal look of ambiance theme with gray bar in the top of the windows.

I already tried a bunch of configs and i still don't get the gray in the top window.

So does anybody know what is might happening?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Reset Unity**

```
unity --reset
```

After that try Downloading From [here](http://www.deviantart.com/download/288407674/fs_icons_ubuntu_by_franksouza183-d4rpksa.zip).

To install the icon theme:

- Extract the .zip file downloaded above
- Extract the .tar.gz files within the ‘FS Icons’ folder
- Go to your Home folder & press Ctrl+H
- Move above folders to the ‘.icons’ directory